# Obtener todas las combinaciones posibles de variables lógicas sin especificar el número de elementos

Tags: r

Estoy intentando obtener todas las combinaciones de un vector. Dado

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
```

Necesito obtener todas las combinaciones posibles sin especificar el número de elementos necesarios y sin tener en cuenta el orden (la solución `{2,3,1}` es la misma que `{1,2,3}`). Por ejemplo, el resultado sería:

```
{}
{3}
{2}
{2,3}
{1}
{1,3}
{1,2}
{1,2,3}
```

Una aproximación sería realizar la siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla lógica]

Estoy seguro de que debe de haber alguna función que realice esta tarea en vez de crear la table e ir formando las soluciones a partir de ella, ya que es poco tedioso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con R base puedes usar `combn()` para generar las combinaciones de `m` elementos de tu vector, por supuesto, para tu ejemplo, deberías generar las combinaciones de 0, 1, 2 y 3 elementos:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
unlist(lapply(0:length(x),function(m) {combn(x, m=m, simplify=FALSE)}), recursive=FALSE)

[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 2

[[6]]
[1] 1 3

[[7]]
[1] 2 3

[[8]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

El retorno, como puedes ver es una lista de 8 elementos, cada uno es una de las combinaciones posibles.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, en la web internacional me dieron una solución a través de un paquete pero esto lo veo más útil.